# Angular [innerHTML] renders content twice

Tags: html, angular

This is is my html:

```
<p class="description" [innerHTML]="standardData.details.description | safeHtml"></p>
```

And i will get 2 "p" tags with my html if it's rendered server side,

I Checked the standardData.details.description and it's fine, but i recently updated my angular to version 16, so mayble it's related to that

This is my Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml' })
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) { }
  transform(value) {
    return value ? this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value) : '';
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the *safeHtml* pipe?

Comment: Rendering content twice with Angular's [innerHTML] binding can be due to Angular's change detection mechanism combined with the usage of a pipe. It's possible that an extra change detection cycle is triggered, resulting in the content being rendered twice.

Comment: I posted a pipe down there

Comment: And this happened when i imported hydration, I added "provideClientHydration()" at the end of providers at app.module.ts

Comment: Can you share the output? Are there 2 `<p>` tags with the `description` class? If so, please also share the code surrounding your HTML snippet

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you are counting the `p` tag that is used to insert the html, then you can modify it to

```
<p class="description" [outerHTML]="standardData.details.description | safeHtml"></p>
```

This will ensure the current element is replaced by the content!